# fullcalendar unable to populate pages hidden by tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I've got a fullcalendar setup, but there are so many pages I've got it set up with tabs, but when I change a date, only the ones currently displayed get updated, the same goes for the initial loading of calendars, it will only load the events for the displayed ones, while the "hidden" ones in inactive tabs don't' get populated at all.
I at first couldn't even get a calendar view going, but I solved this by initiating the $.tabs AFTER the fullcalendar construction was done.

I have a live copy running right now at http://www.stavanger-ishall.no/ (hitting the blue time schedule image should open it for you)

I have attempted working around the problem by adding an event to the "select" option of the tabs to fetch the calendar data then, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the $.tabs() "show" event as opposed to "select" and then running a fetch command on my calendars, this ensured the page had loaded the calendar before trying to populate it.